# jQuery autocomplete minLength

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

The autocomplete never fires on first character entered but 2nd. Although after using back-space it works for the **minLength = 1**.
Also, the **selectFirst:true** never defaults to first item in the array on page load.

```
$().ready(function (){ 
       $('#CompanyName').autocomplete({
                 source: companyNames,
                 select: SetLocations, 
                 selectFirst :true,
                 minLength: 0  //corrected as suggested, but still no change
      });
});
```

Has anybody faced this behavior before. I'm clueless since I haven't any global settings/defaults.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a few syntactical errors, the `document.ready` handler is missing a brace (and is deprecated anyway) and a comma in your options, it should look like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#CompanyName').autocomplete({
             source: companyNames,
             select: SetLocations, 
             selectFirst: true, //here
             minLength: 0
  });
});
```

Also, autocomplete activates *after* `minLength` characters, if you want it immediately, use `0`, [from the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength):

> **minLength**: The minimum number of characters a user has to type before the Autocomplete activates. Zero is useful for local data with just a few items. Should be increased when there are a lot of items, where a single character would match a few thousand items.

.....

Comment: @Nick: Oh, thats my typo. Sorry.  But cross-checked with my code. All commas in place.

Comment: @conqenator - make sure to post your *actual* code, when you just make up code for the question it makes it nearly impossible to answer...you've got at least 2 copy errors in there, a cut/paste shouldn't have this...

Comment: @Nick: Again, apologies.    I dint know .ready() is deprecated. Does that play any role here?

Comment: @conqenator - nope, using `1` instead of `0` is your root issue, but do fix the `.ready()` format none the less :)

Comment: @Nick:Thanks for continuing to help with this. Upgraded to the new .ready() format. minLength: 0. Still, it fires at the 2nd character. And how would I go about setFirst:true. shouldn;t it set the value of the textbox on page load itself?

Comment: @conqenator - Where is this `selectFirst` option coming from? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ it's not part of 1.8 at least, are you using a different version?

Comment: @Nick: jQuery UI 1.8.5 - it's autocomplete. The docs are valid for this version?

Comment: @conqenator - yes...not sure where you found that option, but it's not in the jQuery UI code...

Comment: @Nick: I think it's there until 1.8.4.  https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js

Comment: @conqenator - that's an *extension*, not pat of jQuery UI itself, do you have that extension included?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, I have it included.